# what is the point of having a seperate build function in keras.layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

As per the following doc -->

https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

It is used for initializing the weight matrix.. but my doubt is why not just do this initialization in the call function itself?

Comment: It does do initialization in `Layer.__call__`, actually `Layer.build` will be called in `Layer.__call__` the first time this layer is called

Comment: hey yea u r right I checked the doc.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Build function is simply for abstraction and structuring the code in a better fashion. Finally, build function is called from **call** where we know the input shape. You can also initialize weights in init function if you already know the input shape